# Android- App with Wordpress API e GSON

Tags: android, json, wordpress, api, gson

i'm trying to make an android native app for my Wordpress blog. I heard that Wordpress has JSON-API to handle the information of a blog but I don't know how I could use it. Please, could someone give me a tiny introduction of its use and if I could use the GSON library to manage the information within my Android app? 
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple example to parse/deserialize your JSON string

```
String jsonStr = "{\"name\": \"A\", \"address\":\"XYZ\"}";

// You can convert your Json string to JsonObject as below

Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonElement element = gson.fromJson (jsonStr, JsonElement.class);
JsonObject jsonObj = element.getAsJsonObject();


// If you can define a POJO class for your Json, you can convert json to java object

public class MyData {
    private String name;
    private String address;
    //Setters and Getters   
}

Gson gson = new Gson();
MyData data = gson.fromGson(jsonStr, MyData.class);
```

Refer [Gson API documentation](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/index.html) for more details. Hope this will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

To use GSON you will have to create a class with the exact same fields as the JSON you will want to parse. GSON till then take in a JSON string and instantiate an object with the data. For example if you have some JSON with som information like:

```
{"name":"Test testsson", "id":19}
```

and you would like to parse that. You have to create a class like:

```
Person{
    public String name;
    public int id;  
}
```

And then use GSON:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Person p = gson.fromGson(jsonString, Person.class);
```

and the p object will have the data from your JSON string.